# How to solve cards overlay problem in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make news section to be displayed in blocks like in this photo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idUsC.png)
I created two rows, and put absolute position to box div.
But I got this result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2SIP.png)
How to solve this problem ?
This is the code:
HTML: https://codeshare.io/j00kKP
CSS: https://codeshare.io/VZZk1R

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

You need to give `position: absolute;` to `.block-text` instead of `.block-deck` and `.block-img` and we have made some style change like below:

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/0tbmqor5/2/